# probability of throwing 5 different numbers on 6 dices

Tags: probability

We throw 6 dices, what is the probability of 5 different numbers.

I do not understand the solution:

$$P(5 \, \text{different}) = \frac{\binom{6}{2}\cdot 6 \cdot 1 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{6^6}$$

I understand the sample space : $6^6$,

however I do not understand the numerator if somebody can explain what it means.

Is there a more intuitive way to solve this problem?

Comment: You have $6$ dice and $5$ out of $6$ numbers so two of them will have the same number. ${6 \choose 2}$ chooses two dice that will have the same number. Then for the first die of the two, we have choice of $6$ numbers but for the next, we have only one choice as it must be the same number as on the first die. Then for the third die, there are $5$ choices and so on...

Comment: @MathLover So that means that if we would have 4 different numbers, we would solve it like this: 

$\frac{\binom{6}{3}\cdot 6 \cdot 4!}{6^6}$

Comment: @MathLover would that be correct

Comment: No it is not correct for $4$ different numbers as there are two cases - i) one of the numbers appears on three dice or ii) two of the numbers appear on two dice each.

Comment: Also, for the case of the same number appearing on three dice, we have $6$ choices for the first set of three, $5$ choices for the fourth die, $4$ choices for the fifth die and $3$ choices for the sixth die.

Comment: @MathLover $\frac{\binom{6}{3}\cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 + \binom{6}{2}\cdot 6 \binom{4}{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 4\cdot 3 }{6^6}$

Comment: @MathLover Would that be correct?

Comment: The second term - you have to divide by $2$ as ${6 \choose 2} {4 \choose 2}$ already orders both pairs of dice. Then when you multiply by $6$ choices for the first pair of dice and $5$ choices for the second pair, it will double count.

Comment: As the direct counting gets more complicated, you can instead apply Principle of Inclusion Exclusion or Stirling Number of the second kind which are  more straightforward.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131813/discussion-between-vlc-and-math-lover).

Comment: @MathLover Can you explain what would be the direct procedure for 4 different numbers then...

Answer (score 2):

You noted that you already understand the total number of possible outcomes, so it only remains to determine the number of outcomes with 5 different numbers.

If six dice roll 5 different values, it must be the case that one number is rolled twice and the others are rolled once. There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose which dice are the double, and 6 numbers the diuble could be. Then there are four numbers which are rolled once, for which there are $\binom{5}{4}$ choices, and $4!$ ways to assign them to the 4 singleton dice.

Then the number of possibilities with 5 distinct rolls is:

$$N=\binom{6}{2}\cdot6\cdot\binom{5}{4}\cdot4!\\
=\binom{6}{2}6!$$

Which turns out to be the numerator in the probability calculation.